# Eclipse linker not finding my libraries

Tags: eclipse, gcc, gpu, nvidia, nsight

I am having problems getting NSight Eclipse to link in my libraries:

```
Building target: SA_V1
Invoking: NVCC Linker

nvcc -L/home/streaming/VidApp_V1.0/src/AudioPreconditioning6Ch/dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86 -L/home/streaming/cuda-workspace/libConfig/Debug -L/usr/lib32 -link -o  "SA_V1"  ./V1.1/DeckLinkAPIDispatch.o ./V1.1/DeckLinkAPIDispatch_v7_6.o ./V1.1/audio.o ./V1.1/capture.o ./V1.1/cudaEngine.o ./V1.1/decklink.o ./V1.1/engine.o ./V1.1/filter.o ./V1.1/filterKernel.o ./V1.1/initialize.o ./V1.1/main.o ./V1.1/playback.o ./V1.1/utils.o ./V1.1/videoFuncThread.o ./V1.1/vif.o ./V1.1/vof.o   -llibAudioPreconditioning6Ch.so -lliblibConfig.so -llibtiff.so.4.3.2


/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibAudioPreconditioning6Ch.so
```

==> searching for the library I get:

```
/home/streaming/VidApp_V1.0/src/AudioPreconditioning6Ch/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/libAudioPreconditioning6Ch.so
/home/streaming/VidApp_V1.0/src/AudioPreconditioning6Ch/dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/libAudioPreconditioning6Ch.so
/home/streaming/dist/lib64/libAudioPreconditioning6Ch.so
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library names in Linux are not the same as in Windows.  in VS, i was linking libConfig.lib, so when eclipse asked for the name of the library i typed in:  liblibConfig.so which is the name of the file.  Uh uh. In Linux the prefix lib is understood as a prefix and the suffix .so is also not part of the name. so entering:  libConfig  as the library to load (which gets inserted into make as:  -llibConfig) solves the problem